# Iterate over selected vectors from a std::tuple of vectors

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement the entity-component-system pattern statically in C++11/14. I have managed to make a container for my entities, and I am trying to add functionality to work with the data inside. This is the code I have so far:

```
template<typename... Components>
struct Entity {
  std::tuple<Components...> comps;

  Entity() = default;
  Entity(Components... cs) {
    comps = std::make_tuple(cs...);
  };
};

template<typename... EntityTypes>
struct EntityCollection {
  std::tuple<std::vector<EntityTypes>...> entities;

  template<typename EntityType>
  void add(EntityType e) {
    auto& cont = std::get<std::vector<EntityType>>(entities);
    cont.push_back(e);
  };

  template<typename... Components, typename F>
  void for_each_containing(F f) {
     // todo... apply f on all entities for which 'Components' 
     // are a subset of those in the entity.
  };

};
```

I've seen code that loops through all the elements in a tuple using boost fusion (and with the stl adaptor) and generic lambdas like this:

```
// inside entity class
void update() {
  for_each(comps, [](auto& c) { c.update(); }; // assuming all components has an update function
};
```

However, I would like to apply a function an all entities that contains a certain set of components, like the for_each_containing function suggests. I have been trying to write something using the filter_view in fusion, however without success...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does "containing" mean? has exactly the same `Components` as listed in `for_each_containing` in the same order or arbitrary order? or has any of the Components? or the Components i `for_each_containing` is a subset of those from Entities?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I've updated the question. I want f to apply on all entities where 'Components' are a subset of those in the entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utility tools:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
struct pack {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool Contains = false;

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool Contains<T, U, Ts...> = Contains<T, Ts...>;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool Contains<T, T, Ts...> = true;

template <bool...> 
constexpr bool All = true;

template <bool Head, bool... Tail>
constexpr bool All<Head, Tail...> = Head && All<Tail...>;

template <typename Subset, typename Set>
struct IsSubset;

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct IsSubset<pack<Ts...>, pack<Us...>>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, All<Contains<Ts, Us...>...>> {};
```

`Entity` with a sample `update` member function:

```
template <typename... Components>
struct Entity
{
    std::tuple<Components...> comps;

    Entity() = default;

    Entity(Components... cs)
        : comps(cs...)
    {
    }

    void update()
    {
        std::cout << "Updating " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

`EntityCollection` with the `apply` function:

```
template <typename... EntityTypes>
struct EntityCollection
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<EntityTypes>...> entities;

    template <typename EntityType>
    void add(EntityType e)
    {
        auto& cont = std::get<std::vector<EntityType>>(entities);
        cont.push_back(e);
    }

    template <typename... Components, typename F>
    void for_each_containing(F f)
    {        
        using expander = int[];
        (void)expander{ 0, (void(
             apply<Components...>(std::get<std::vector<EntityTypes>>(entities), f)
        ), 0)... };
    }

    template <typename... Components, typename... Ts, typename F>
    auto apply(std::vector<Entity<Ts...>>& entities, F f)
        -> std::enable_if_t<IsSubset<pack<Components...>, pack<Ts...>>{}>
    {
        for (auto& v : entities)
        {
            f(v);
        }
    }   

    template <typename... Components, typename... Ts, typename F>
    auto apply(std::vector<Entity<Ts...>>&, F)
        -> std::enable_if_t<!IsSubset<pack<Components...>, pack<Ts...>>{}>
    {
    } 
};
```

*Tests:*

```
int main()
{
    Entity<int, short> a;
    Entity<long, int> b;
    Entity<float, double> c;

    EntityCollection<Entity<int, short>,
                     Entity<long, int>,
                     Entity<float, double>> collection;

    collection.add(a);
    collection.add(b);
    collection.add(c);

    collection.for_each_containing<int>([](auto& c){ c.update(); });

    collection.for_each_containing<float>([](auto& c){ c.update(); });

    collection.for_each_containing<short>([](auto& c){ c.update(); });

    collection.for_each_containing<short, int>([](auto& c){ c.update(); });
}
```

*Output:*

```
Updating void Entity<int, short>::update() [Components = <int, short>]
Updating void Entity<long, int>::update() [Components = <long, int>]

Updating void Entity<float, double>::update() [Components = <float, double>]

Updating void Entity<int, short>::update() [Components = <int, short>]

Updating void Entity<int, short>::update() [Components = <int, short>]
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ece9ddc599e75a)

Comment: Really cool! This was what I wanted. Thanks! I have a few questions: why does the expander expression start with a zero? What does the void keywords do in the same expression? And why do you use '&&'  instead of just '&'? Will the entities me moved out of the vectors or will they still be valid. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shump `expander` starts with `0` to handle cases where `EntityTypes` is empty. `void` makes the compiler ignore any result from `apply` (actually not necessary if apply returns `void` itself). `auto&&` can bind to anything, but I changed it now to `auto&` to make it work only with lvalues

Comment: `All<Contains<Ts, Us...>...>` This is great, much cleaner than what had occurred to me.